# Current rating for busbars

Tags: current-rating

How does one go about calculating the current rating of self produced busbars?
Store bought wires are a lot easier, as they have the derating factors for parallel wires and ambient temperature readily available (e.g. Radox: http://www.beichang.cn/pdf/RADOX%20CURRENT%20CARRYING%20CAPACITY.pdf)
Do the manufacturers just come to these conclusions through testing?
I know there are a lot of factors playing into this, but am just looking for a ballpark estimate. [This link](https://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm) is useful, but is for wires and not busbars. Will there be a meaningful difference?
My copper busbars have a cross section of 9mm2, and are exposed to good air flow. I am also interested in short time current burst ratings. Any advice/sources would be great, thank you!

Comment: Resistivity of material * length / area is a good starting point then de-rate...

Comment: Afaik, wire current ratings are mostly to protect the plastic from overheating. You might have other constraints, such as voltage drop, or temperature of other materials around your bus bar. Therefore it is hard to get to a "rating", but you can definetively estimate voltage drop and power dissipation if you know the material, length and cross section. Temperature rise will be a bit more difficult, since it will depend on shape and airflow.

Answer (score 1):

A very good source of information with regards to copper is ... the [Copper Alliance's documentation relating to ratings and sizing](http://copperalliance.org.uk/docs/librariesprovider5/pub-22-copper-for-busbars/copper-for-busbars-all-sections.pdf?sfvrsn=2).

Your example is a common case for busbars and a convenient method to use is sizing by specific heat capacity: the amount of energy needed to raise a mass of material's temperature by a given amount.

> \$Q=S\cdot m\cdot t \$
>
> \$t_r = \frac{Q}{S\cdot m}\$
>
> \$Q\$ = amount of heat energy added (J)
>   \$S\$ = specific heat capacity of the material (J/kg/K or J/kg/°C)
>   \$m\$ = mass of the bar (kg)
>   \$t_r\$ = temperature rise (K or °C)

Where the energy dissipated in the bar \$Q\$ is:

> \$Q = P\cdot T\$
>
> P = power dissipated (W)
>   T = Time the power is dissipated over (s)

Thus:

> \$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ t_r = \frac{P \cdot T}{S \cdot m}\$
>   \$\therefore \Delta t_r = \frac{P}{S\cdot m} \$

The power dissipated is the ohmic loss (copper loss):

> \$P = I^2 R\$

Or, using the characteristics (resistivity and dimensions) of the material:

> \$P= I^2 \frac{\rho l}{A}\$
>
> \$\rho\$ = resistivity of the material (Ω·m)
>   \$l\$ = length of the bar (m)
>   \$A\$ = cross-sectional area of the bar (m<sup>2</sup>)

And so:

> \$\Delta t_r = \frac{I^2 \cdot \rho \cdot l}{A \cdot S \cdot D \cdot l \cdot A}\$
>
> \$\ \ \ \ \ \ =\frac{I^2 \cdot \rho}{A^2 \cdot S \cdot D}\$
>
> \$\ \ \ \ \ \ = \frac{\rho}{S \cdot D} \cdot (\frac{I}{A})^2 \$
>
> \$D\$ = Density (kg·m<sup>−3</sup>)

Essentially these are the steps I go through (originally sourced from the copper alliance 15years ago) to provide a 1st pass sizing & suitability. The entire document contains useful information as well pertaining to copper for current carrying

Comment: Heat capacity is only important for applications that don't reach steady state.

Comment: true and the original query was about "short term burst". There is a lot of considerations needed when sizing a busbar and unfortunately none of that information is provided in the OP. However... as a source of general information the copper allegiance is ideal. An excerpt was provided rather than just a url incase the url decay's and equally one of the considerations w.r.t. copper busbars

Answer (score 0):

Normally this kind of thing is done with charts and nomographs. To determine the temperature rise would require CFD simulation of the convection cooling the bars.

Here is a very old (probably 1920s or earlier) set of charts from the Standard Handbook for Electrical Engineers (8th edition, 1949), and credited to Westinghouse.

Obviously current carrying capability will be less for AC that for the same configuration carrying DC because of skin effect. Inductance can also be an issue with these kinds of currents, even at 50/60Hz. The charts are for 60Hz and 35 degrees C rise.

[image]

Refer to @JonRB's answer for the "burst" situation. If it's a relatively short burst with a long time for recovery you can treat the situation as adiabatic rise above the steady state using the heat capacity as he suggests.